# Opus on Java using libjitsi

Tags: java, opus

I've been trying to get Opus to work with my VOIP application for the past few days, and it's driving me up the wall. Looking through the libjitsi library, I found a couple of methods that I thought were perfect for my application. However, I'm not getting the right data out of the decode.

My code:

```
// -----------------------BEGIN Try Opus Encoding
long opusEnc = Opus.encoder_create(SAMPLE_RATE, 1);

byte[] bytebuffin = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE * 2];
byte[] bytebuffout = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE * 2];

Random rand = new Random();

rand.nextBytes(bytebuffin);

System.out.println("Begin Encode");
System.out.print("In  ");

for (int i = 0; i < bytebuffin.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(bytebuffin[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();

int res = Opus.encode(opusEnc, bytebuffin, 0, CHUNK_SIZE, bytebuffout, 0, bytebuffout.length);
System.out.println("res " + res);

System.out.print("\nOut ");

for (int i = 0; i < bytebuffout.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(bytebuffout[i] + " ");
}

System.out.println("End Encode");

System.out.println("Begin Decode");

byte[] output = new byte[res];

for (int i = 0; i < res; i++) {
    output[i] = bytebuffout[i];
}

System.out.print("\nCompressed ");
for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(output[i] + " ");
}

byte[] deflatedData = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE * 2];

long opusDec = Opus.decoder_create(SAMPLE_RATE, 1);
System.out.println("\nopusDec " + opusDec);

int numSamp = Opus.decoder_get_nb_samples(opusDec, bytebuffout, 0, output.length);
System.out.println("numSamp " + numSamp);

int res2 = -1;
res2 = Opus.decode(opusDec, output, 0, output.length, deflatedData, 0, numSamp, 0);

System.out.println("res2 " + res2);

System.out.print("\nDecoded ");
for (int i = 0; i < deflatedData.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(deflatedData[i] + " ");
}

System.out.println("End Decode");
Opus.decoder_destroy(opusDec);

// Opus.encoder_destroy(opusEnc);
// ---------------------END Try Opus Encoding
```

The output looks like this:

Begin Encode
In  -64 52 87 104 -78 -126 -108 -117 78 18 -124 75 -56 -51 -82 89 -88 -107 -86 -88 83 56 127 -31 -115 68 -101 -88 73 -90 -77 -101 61 30 109 -115 36 57 -113 -116 69 120 -11 -43 58 -47 -13 -71 36 -79 29 -99 103 -59 -15 75 -13 -107 111 -126 -93 -72 -30 -117 -65 13 -16 -24 114 33 31 72 52 116 -84 41 88 61 121 -53 -61 -42 75 127 -78 90 73 91 119 82 -16 -121 -94 -83 -42 -49 7 -18 28 23 -14 -40 -125 -76 -14 -54 44 -127 30 2 -88 77 -97 57 -83 -106 -35 63 -4 -17 -39 111 -123 -23 -27 -124 -53 -32 41 38 -83 3 -63 100 33 -19 -51 -121 100 61 -20 70 101 97 102 122 -111 14 -107 92 29 -42 -110 -99 -70 -36 -82 7 -5 -54 12 80 -62 78 61 -26 -45 46 5 -41 122 -17 7 115 116 -4 -39 69 -128 0 11 -75 -26 28 76 71 17 20 99 -39 70 46 -21 62 34 -106 -119 95 85 -14 79 -80 -81 42 23 -58 -31 102 78 67 -97 53 117 -10 102 -31 102 103 32 125 14 24 -28 -42 -42 85 125 -98 12 -120 -25 110 82 81 -106 -95 -88 -128 -9 36 47 83 119 92 -117 19 -92 7 113 41 -20 114 -34 -116 -86 -74 50 46 -71 85 -14 -80 -77 35 45 -120 52 113 -87 -100 127 -66 121 29 -77 1 10 -15 -60 -75 -75 92 -97 -91 -92 108 -23 -71 53 -114 121 12 -87 -71 -110 -94 -17 -51 -48 -125 -17 21 84 106 62 -16 -80 19 52 34 20 -123 -83 -74 16 52 87 -88 -29 -84 107 -81 97 18 102 20 47 -69 30 49 121 -92 -77 -62 127 -61 35 -18 1 26 79 -75 -19 68 -122 -27 -67 -42 -112 -51 85 41 52 -43 -57 21 -98 -38 -78 81 49 16 -115 51 16 -68 113 83 -29 -116 48 -109 34 16 -22 -37 -91 114 38 -121 14 119 -89 77 67 51 -43 68 -115 -15 115 -96 22 -92 -45 107 -122 86 5 -21 -54 99 104 28 123 -36 -41 75 30 117 -80 -63 52 77 -86 -47 32 36 76 51 -78 62 80 96 -83 90 -23 -50 122 -86 96 122 58 74 -39 31 -85 4 87 29 61 20 -127 91 -122 -106 8 -25 -89 -81 110 -11 81 -20 -85 87 74 1 14 -97 -76 -84 -21 85 41 -58 -17 -57 7 -64 38 -128 1 -38 -14 -24 48 88 -59 53 
res 56

Out -24 126 -113 -84 7 -17 54 117 -97 44 -11 35 -80 105 80 -64 -5 -125 47 -97 3 103 117 -15 117 -123 -78 -123 28 -1 -9 -52 -79 -65 66 -32 43 39 -32 125 -119 -89 -95 -69 1 -32 -75 -75 75 -60 -43 39 -29 115 58 72 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
End Encode

Begin Decode
Compressed -24 126 -113 -84 7 -17 54 117 -97 44 -11 35 -80 105 80 -64 -5 -125 47 -97 3 103 117 -15 117 -123 -78 -123 28 -1 -9 -52 -79 -65 66 -32 43 39 -32 125 -119 -89 -95 -69 1 -32 -75 -75 75 -60 -43 39 -29 115 58 72
opusDec 140641825591296
numSamp 240
res2 240

Decoded 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 -1 -1 1 0 0 0 -1 -1 1 0 -1 -1 1 0 0 0 -1 -1 2 0 -2 -1 1 0 1 0 -3 -1 3 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 2 0 -2 -1 1 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 1 0 0 0 -1 -1 2 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 2 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 2 0 -1 -1 0 0 2 0 -1 -1 0 0 1 0 -1 -1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 -1 -1 1 0 -1 -1 1 0 1 0 -4 -1 6 0 -3 -1 -3 -1 8 0 -10 -1 5 0 2 0 -9 -1 10 0 -7 -1 1 0 5 0 -8 -1 8 0 -5 -1 0 0 6 0 -9 -1 7 0 -1 -1 -5 -1 7 0 -4 -1 -2 -1 4 0 -2 -1 -4 -1 6 0 -2 -1 -5 -1 9 0 -6 -1 -2 -1 8 0 -7 -1 1 0 5 0 -5 -1 0 0 5 0 -6 -1 2 0 8 0 -13 -1 9 0 -3 -1 -9 -1 22 0 6 0 -1 -1 -25 -1 6 0 -9 -1 30 0 82 0 -113 -1 -2 -1 44 0 -88 -1 -109 0 41 0 -109 -1 10 0 -58 -1 -11 -1 93 0 -30 -1 -36 -1 -30 0 88 -1 -65 -2 104 1 -63 -1 -57 -1 35 1 -67 -3 -72 0 108 1 71 -3 -105 2 -86 0 40 -4 -99 3 -128 0 84 -4 -56 1 97 -2 101 -1 -82 3 -122 -2 -123 -1 126 1 -53 -1 3 1 -34 -2 26 -2 7 0 83 0 -98 0 45 0 -44 -1 10 -2 105 -1 -26 1 32 0 8 2 35 -1 42 -2 73 5 -6 -3 7 -3 -54 2 -83 -7 58 2 -28 6 -38 -9 122 2 -115 5 46 -7 -22 3 64 1 -57 -7 16 4 114 -1 126 -1 -107 4 -34 -6 70 -2 122 4 65 -1 -99 -1 -32 1 74 -1 -79 -2 96 0 -96 -3 75 2 99 4 54 -4 -128 1 54 -1 26 -5 107 5 49 1 -97 -2 -72 -1 9 -3 -35 0 -38 0 100 2 10 -2 82 -3 46 2 -4 -5 58 2 -8 1 79 -6 -43 0 13 1 
End Decode

Summary: I seem to be getting compressed data from Opus.encode, but when I try Opus.decode, the returned data does not seem right at all. I've also tried applying this to voice data and it is incomprehensible.

Am I using the Opus methods wrongly? Or is my fundamental understanding of libjitsi Opus flawed?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem, but I can't clearly remember the steps (it was over a month ago). However, if anyone stumbles across the same problem, here are a few pointers to help you go in the right direction.

1. Note that Opus is a stateful codec, meaning that the encoding or decoding of one frame affects the next frame. This means that for every audio stream, you should be using the same encoder / decoder instance across frames. DO NOT use one encoder or decoder instance to process different streams.
2. Opus requires frames of particular lengths (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6716). It's much harder to get it to work with frame sizes that are not "normal" as far as the codec was designed.
3. Properly framing your audio data using headers and sanity checks helps a lot to make sure you are on the right track. The compressed data is not decoded per data unit (i.e. short), but *by frame*. If the data you pass to the decoder has lacking or excess bits that are not part of the same encoded audio frame, you get garbage.

Good luck codecing!